# Concerns limited by static table names

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have a method that is common to two models which I would like to share via a concern.

The method includes an activerecord join statement that specifies the name of the table "Regions".

Is there any way the table name can be dynamic to reflect the current class?

```
def children
  children = Region.joins("LEFT JOIN Regions AS ancestor ON ancestor.lft BETWEEN #{lft}+1 AND #{rgt}-1 AND Regions.lft BETWEEN ancestor.lft+1 AND ancestor.rgt-1")
  children = children.where("ancestor.id IS NULL")
  children = children.where(lft: (lft+1..rgt-1))
  return children
end
```

Comment: You opened several questions around the same issue, and you never approved a single answer.

Comment: Hi Simon the others are different questions on the same subject of ActiveRecord. Whilst they have responses they are not answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the `children` method is defined in a concern as a class method, then you have access to all the class methods from the model using the concern. This means that you can call `joins` directly without specifying the model class.

You can use [`table_name`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ModelSchema/ClassMethods.html#method-i-table_name) or `quoted_table_name` to get the table name of the current model for use in the query conditions.

```
def children
  result = joins("LEFT JOIN #{table_name} AS ancestor ON ancestor.lft BETWEEN #{lft}+1 AND #{rgt}-1 AND #{table_name}.lft BETWEEN ancestor.lft+1 AND ancestor.rgt-1")
  result = result.where("ancestor.id IS NULL")
  result.where(lft: (lft+1..rgt-1))
end
```

Also, the last `return` statement is unnecessary since Ruby always returns the last executed line in a method. I have also changed the variable name holding the result since it was the same as the method name (`children`), which *can* lead to nasty errors.

Comment: If defined as a ClassMethod I do not believe I have access to the instance variables #{lft} & #{rgt}.

Comment: @user1567212 That is correct. If you make it an instance method, you can use `class.joins` on the first line. Same for `class.table_name`.

Comment: Can I clarify that I am unable to make this a class method due to the instance varaibles #{lft} and #{rgt} ? I now have this method working in my concern however I had to use "self.class.table_name" to get it to work. From what I have read this method should be within the "included do" section of the concern however it works both ways so I am confused as to it's purpose.